# VBA - ComboBox getting compile error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Spent 4 hours on this, no result.  I get a compile error,"method or data not found" for this particular userform (UserformX).  But it works fine, perfect in another UserformY.  Why am I getting a compile error?

Objective:  I want to simply populate a ComboBox1 with 2,000 job titles.   This list of 2,000 job titles sits in the tab "Background".  Please help?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     Dim oneTitle As Range
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("Background")
        For Each oneTitle In ws.Range("A3:A2003")
            With UserFormX.ComboBox1
               .AddItem ComboBox1.Value
               .List(.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = ComboBox1.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End With
        Next oneTitle 
End Sub
```

Error screenshot...

[image]

Comment: `ComboBox1` is a `ComboBox` control, it doesn't have an `Offset` method. Did you mean `oneTitle.Offset(0, 1).Value`?

Comment: Just tried as you suggested, but now I'm getting compile error for .ComboBox1.Listcount . . . why?

Comment: The funny thing is that my original code worked just fine in another userform... weird!!

Comment: I can assure you that `MyComboBox.Offset` only ever worked if you had a `Range` variable that you named `MyComBoBox`.

Comment: You're getting a compile error because `ComboBox1.ListCount` is inside a `With UserFormX.ComboBox1` block - you want `.ListCount`

Comment: Based on this "*The funny thing is that my original code worked just fine in another userform... weird!! – SofiaEd*", I am obligated to advise you to check your VBE settings and ensure `Require Variable Declarations` is enabled and that `Option Explicit` is used in all of your modules.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Coding questions belong on https://stackoverflow.com/ and are much more likely to get good answers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are getting an error because, the used method is for Multiple Column Combobox, and you are tying to populate data from One Column only.*

*Remember the Offset is used to add second column value and the code should,,*

```
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = XPart.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Where `XPart` is a Range.

---

***This simple VBA code will fix the issue:***

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = [Sheet2!A1:A10].Value
End Sub
```

---

**Named Range can be used also, to populate Combobox.**

*How it works:*

- From **F**ormulas TAB click **D**efine Name.
- For **N**ew Name dialog box enter a name for the range, `JobTitle` and in the **R**efers, enter the following formula:

  ```
  =OFFSET(Background!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Background!$A:$A)-1,1)
  ```
- Finish with **O**k.

***C***opy & **P**aste this code.

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rngJob As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = Worksheets("Background")

For Each rngJob In ws.Range("JobTitle")

  Me.cboJobs.AddItem rngJob.Value

Next rngJob

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

*Benefit of  using Named Range is, that Excel automatically streaches the data range if & when the new value added.*

*Adjust Sheet, Combobox, Range name, also Cell references in the code as needed.*

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh!!  You came through again!!  Done.

Comment: Gald to help you @SofiaEd,, keep asking ☺